# Trying to find a counterexample for a limit result

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\lim_{x \to c } g(x) = A $ and $\lim_{x \to A} h(x) = B$. Is it true that $\lim_{x \to c} h(g(x)) = B $?

I feel like this result is false. but I am trying to find a counter example using piecewise functions but I cant seem to make it work. I have the feeling that this result would be true if we say $h$ is continuous at $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added later: In answer to the question: When does $\lim_{x\to c} h\circ g (x) = B$ always hold with the given hypotheses? There are two cases: i) $h$ is defined only in a deleted neighborhood of $A.$ Then the conclusion holds iff $g(x)$ is never equal to $A$ in some deleted neighbohood of $c.$ ii) $h$ is defined in a full neighborhood of $A.$ Then the conclusion holds iff $h$ is continuous at $A.$

---

It is indeed false. Here's an example: Define $h(x) = 0, x\ne 0,  h(0) = 1.$ Then $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x) = 0.$ Let $g(x) = x\sin (1/x), x \ne 0, g(0) = 0.$ Then $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=0.$ But $\lim_{x\to 0} h\circ g (x)$ fails to exist. To see this, consider the sequences $1/(2n\pi)$ and $1/(\pi/2 + 2n\pi).$ Both sequences $\to 0,$ but along the first sequence $h\circ g$ is $1,$ and along the second sequence $h\circ g$ is $0.$

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood your example. You are correct.

Comment: So, for this to be true we need $h$ to be continuoues correct?

Comment: ???? what conditions do we need for the above to be true?

Comment: I added to my answer.